# JSDoc VSCode How to define this with callback function?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am doing a class library and some function like jQuery.each().

How to define [this] in callback function?

Demo code:

```js
/** 
 * @this {Car} 
 * @type {function(Car):boolean} 
 */
var callback_tips = function () { }
var Cars = [];
class Car {
    constructor(name) { this.name = name; this.x = 0; }
    Forward(step) { this.x += step; }

    /** @param {callback_tips} callback */
    static Each(callback) {
        for (let car of Cars) { callback.apply(car, car); }
    }
}
(function main() {
    Cars = [new Car('A'), new Car('B'), new Car('C')];
    console.log(Cars);
    Car.Each(function (car) { this.name += this.name; this.Forward(5); });
    console.log(Cars);
})();
```

Output:

```js
[ Car { name: 'A', x: 0 },
  Car { name: 'B', x: 0 },
  Car { name: 'C', x: 0 } ]
[ Car { name: 'AA', x: 5 },
  Car { name: 'BB', x: 5 },
  Car { name: 'CC', x: 5 } ]
```

VsCode Screenshots:

[Callback tips is working (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha60p.png)  
then
[But this do not work (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeZoG.png)